# How can I determine if a character is alpha?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have a list of phone numbers that sometimes have a person in parenthesis at the end. I need to extract the person's name (and add that as a note in a separate field). Here is an example of the data:

```
(517)234-6789(Bob)
701-556-2345
(325)663-5977
(215)789-8585
425-557-7745(Pauline)
```

There is always a () around the person's name, but often there is also a () around the area code, so I can't use the ( as a way to know a name has started. I'd like to create a loop that goes through the phone number string and if it sees alpha characters, builds a string that will be assigned to a variable as the name.

Something like this. I am making up the IS-ALPHA syntax, of course. That is what I am looking for, or something where I don't have to list every letter.

```
PROCEDURE CreatePhoneNote (INPUT cPhone AS CHARACTER)
    DEFINE VARIABLE cPersonName AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE VARIABLE cThisChar AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE VARIABLE iCount AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.

    DO iCount 1 TO LENGTH(cPhone):
        cThisChar = SUBSTRING(cPhone,iCount,1).
        IF IS_ALPHA(cThisChar) THEN cPersonName = cPersonName + cThisChar.
    END.
    
    //etc.....
   
END PROCEDURE.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since these are the fun questions, just one more isAlpha answer that does not use hard-coded ASCII codes but leans on the property / assumption that an alpha character has an upper and lower case version:

```
function isAlpha returns logical (
   i_cc as char
):

    return compare( upper( i_cc ), '<>', lower( i_cc ), 'case-sensitive' ).
  
end function.
```

With some code to test the function:

```
// test
def var ic as int.

do ic = 0 to 255:
   if isAlpha( chr(ic) ) then
      message ic chr( ic ).
end.
```

And then you see that the hard-coded ASCII answer did not take characters with diacritics into account. :-)

Watch it run on [ProgressAblDojo](https://abldojo.services.progress.com/?shareId=62b9a26f3fb02369b2548fb8).

Watch it run again on [ProgresAblDojo](https://abldojo.services.progress.com/?shareId=62baa93b3fb02369b2548fbb) with a fix to help ProgressAblDojo over it's ignorance of it's own codepage.

Comment: This doesn't show diacritics, since they aren't in the 0 - 255 codepoint range. And yes, internationalisation is hard/painful.

Comment: Ah, but it does. AblDojo, which is running with cpinternal iso8859-1 is showing character codes 192 thru 214 and more as alpha since they are letters with diacritics. Unfortunately AblDojo is /rendering/ these characters incorrectly since the output console is ignorant of the session codepage and simply expects utf-8.

Comment: One day I will learn to read, and/or do maths and realise that 127 < 255 (doh!). Stefan is, of course, right. Especially in that hard-coding things is bad.

Answer (score 0):

i can not comment, but a suggestion is to see what character is at the 0th index of the string, if it is a ( then you know how to deal with that condition. Although the next method will only work for usa numbers (it does seem that is what you have), you can check if the length matches a set number (10 since there are 10 digits in a usa number, or 12 since that is how long it would be with 2 parenthesis), and if its not, you know you have a name at the end. You would then split that string at the appropriate index

Comment: Bear in mind that ABL is a 1-based language, so there isn't really a 0th index/item.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the ABL's [`ASC()`](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/abl-reference/page/ASC-function.html?labelkey=product_openedge_125) function.

```
if asc(cThisChar) ge 65 
and asc(cThisChar) le 90
and asc(cThisChar) ge 97 
and asc(cThisChar) le 122
then
   cPersonName = cPersonName + cThisChar.
```

ASC() works simply enough for all codepages for codepoints between 0 and 255; for others it'll depend on your `-cpinternal` / `session:cpinternal` value.

Comment: Ah, that is clever, thank you!

Comment: So I cannot have a name with é, ë, ì, ö and all their diacritic friends? ;-)

Comment: Diacritic friends are left as an exercise to the reader :P

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to go through each character. You can use the open parenthesis to break up the string and get the data after the last parenthesis. This may run faster if you have a large amount of data.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cPhone AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO INITIAL "(517)234-6789(Bob)".
DEFINE VARIABLE cPersonName AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE iCount AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE iNum AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.

iCount = NUM-ENTRIES(cPhone, "(").  /* See how many open parentheses there are */
cPersonName = ENTRY(iCount, cPhone, "(").  /* Get the string after the last open paren */

iNum = INTEGER(SUBSTRING(cPersonName, 1, 1)) NO-ERROR. /* See if the first character is a number */
IF iNum > 0 THEN
    cPersonName = "".  /* If it's a number, there is no name so blank out the variable */
ELSE
    cPersonName = SUBSTRING(cPersonName, 1, LENGTH(cPersonName) - 1).  /* Drop the closed paren */
     
MESSAGE cPersonName VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFORMATION.
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you for that efficient and elegant solution.